# How exactly would you prove this?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, limits

Would this just be the points on the boundaries between $U$ and $\mathbb{R}^n - U$? since any radius greater than $0$ would result in a ball including both $U$ and $\mathbb{R}^n - U$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I've edited your question to not use a picture, so that it's more easily searchable. In the future, you should typeset the question too ^_^

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Show that $C=(\operatorname{cl}U)\cap\operatorname{cl}(\Bbb R^n\setminus U$), and use the fact that the intersection of two closed sets is closed. (And yes, this set is the boundary of both $U$ and $\Bbb R^n\setminus U$.)

Answer (score 0):

Take $b$ in the closure of $C$; we want to see that $b\in C$.

Take an open neighborhood $V$ of $b$; then there exists $a\in C$ such that $a\in V$. Take an open neighborhood $W$ of $a$ such that $W\subseteq V$. Then $W$ intersects both $U$ and $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus U$, and therefore also $V$ does.

You can use open balls, if you prefer, but it just adds complications. This proof holds in every topological space.